# Auctex: Make it open a file chooser when inserting a href command

Tags: auctex

If I run `C-c C-m href` in auctex, it asks me which url to use. However if I want to link to a local file, it should let me choose the file but it doesn't.

How can I achieve this? Would be ok to bind this for example to `C-u C-c C-m href` or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

In order to override current definition of `href` completion, add the following code to your init file:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "hyperref"
  '(TeX-add-symbols
    '("href" [ (TeX-arg-key-val LaTeX-hyperref-href-options) ]
      (TeX-arg-file "URL") "Text" ignore)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't start in the local direcotry (but in root) and it seems to have permission problems if I navigate to my home dir.

Comment: It does start form current directory for me.  `TeX-arg-file` is based on `read-file-name', are you sure you don't have some customizations influencing its behavior?

Comment: I tried to narrow it down by commenting out piece by piece in my `.emacs`. It seems to interfer with `(helm-mode 1)`

Comment: I use helm too and I don't have this problem.